# How can i Add or substract on data already existing in mysql Db.(c#)

Tags: c#, mysql

How can i Add or substract on data already existing in mysql Db.(c#)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK10E.png)

```
try
            {
                conn = new MySqlConnection(cs.ConnString);
                conn.Open();
                cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText= "update Compte set Solde_Actuel_$ = Solde_Actuel_$ - " + MontantDollars_AAS_txt.Text + " WHERE Code_Compte='" + Code_txt.Text + "'";
                cmd.ExecuteReader();
                conn.Close();                 

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to create an SQL command. Use parameterized statements. See [why it's a bad idea and how to fix it](//bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your Mysql Server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Code_Compte='C-81956" at line 1

Comment: @patrickskic: Then you have an error in your SQL syntax.  When you debug, what is the runtime value of `cmd.CommandText`?  What do you expect it to be?  Why?  Correcting the SQL injection problem by using parameterized queries will likely render the problem moot.

Comment: let me give that a try

Comment: Side note. While it will work as well with ExecuteReader, to execute update, insert, delete statements you should use _ExecuteNonQuery_.

Comment: How are going to subtract a string from probably a decimal in your database - I hope.

Answer (score 0):

I use MSSQL server and your code works for me.
The data were successfully updated.
I think there may be a problem with runtime value of your .Text variable

```
    try
    {
        var propertyText = "Test2";

        var conn = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
        conn.Open();
        var cmd = new SqlCommand
        {
            Connection = conn,
            CommandText = "update Terminals set Zipcode = " + 123 + " WHERE Name='" + propertyText + "'"
        };
        cmd.ExecuteReader();
        conn.Close();
    }
```